# SPSS-independent-sample-t-test

Tags: bonferroni

I want to test mean differences between 4(0,1,2,3) groups for 6 different cell-types. In other words, I would have 6 comparisons to do for each cell-type (0-1,0-2,0-3,1-2,1-3,2-3). I have run a repeated-measures ANOVA before but it only gives me the main effects and interactions. To correct my t-tests for multiple comparisons, I would use Bonferroni, does SPSS let me do that, I just cannot seem to find it except as part of the means-testing using ANOVA? Or do I have to do it manually and how would i do that? alpha-level here is 0.05.Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your question is answered [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60383/bonferroni-adjustment-in-spss-what-does-it-do).

Comment: thank you!might just opt for a one-way ANOVA because SPSS does not seem to do the Bonferroni with multiple t-tests, so would need to do that manually, best to do that i should think.Thanks!