# Bonferroni Correction p value in SPSS

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, p-value, bonferroni

I have run an analysis on data using SPSS. I have a repeated measures design with 7 conditions. I chose to do pairwise comparisons to see where the effects lie and used the Bonferroni correction. If I've understood it correctly k(k-1)/2 would give an adjusted p value of .002. However, what I'm confused with is the output in SPSS. It says something is significant at .003. Could somebody explain this and how would I report it? I wasn't sure if I was supposed to check the significance value against the new .002 one and therefore should conclude it isn't significant.

Answer (score 1):

With [Bonferroni correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) you multiply the $p$-values by the number of comparisons that you made, so you can calculate it by hand. SPSS calculates it exactly the same way

> Statistical textbooks often present Bonferroni adjustment (or
>   correction) in the following terms. First, divide the desired
>   alpha-level by the number of comparisons. Second, use the number so
>   calculated as the p-value for determining significance. So, for
>   example, with alpha set at .05, and three comparisons, the LSD p-value
>   required for significance would be .05/3 = .0167.

(source [IBM's page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476685); cf. [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60383/bonferroni-adjustment-in-spss-what-does-it-do)).

---

I imagine that the difference could be caused by different way of [rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) that was used or some other trivial reason.

Comment: okay, so really I should just trust how SPSS is reporting it.